# Javascript regex to extract herf and text for anchor tags with other tags inside link

Tags: javascript, regex

I have HTML response as string and contains a tags in the following format:

```
<a href="LINK#"><div></div><span>ANCHOR TAG TEXT</span></a>
```

I want to extract `LINK#` and `ANCHOR TAG TEXT` from all `<a>` tags. There can be different number of `<div>` tags inside `<a>` tag body,

```
const regex = "<a(.*?)</a>";
  const found = ress.match(regex);
  console.log(found);
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454

Comment: Its a HTML response converted to string. Updated my question. Sorry

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

`<a .*href="(.+)".*>.*<span>(.*)<\/span>.*<\/a>`

It captures the contents of the anchor element `href` attribute (between the quotation marks), then captures the text of a span element that is anywhere as a descendent of the anchor element.